# Connect to multiple PPP interfaces with dynamic IP addresses simultaneously

Tags: linux, networking, routing, network-interface

I have a web server that listens on `eth0` and performs queries via multiple `ppp0`, `ppp1`, ..., `pppN` (these are 3G modems) interfaces during a request.

Is it possible in Linux to set up routing in a way that would allow to use both `eth0` and `ppp` simultaneously?

As far as [the research](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System) [shows](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html), it can be done if all interfaces have static IP addresses, but in my case some of them can be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can set the default gateway to any interface you want, `eth0`, `ppp0`. If it looks like a NIC, you can do it. The command is `ip route add default via {ip address}`.
- If the IP address is dynamic, you need to execute the above command when DHCP gets an answer from a DHCP server. `dhclient`, the DHCP client you are likely using, supports running custom scripts when DHCP events occur.

  - But you will first need to execute an `ip route del default {old-ip-address}` to remove the old non-working default gateway.
- A system with two default gateways won't automatically work the way you seem to be expecting.

  - The default route is just that - the route Linux uses when it has no other route to throw a packet at. By configuring a default route, you are saying "ANY traffic that you can't find a destination for goes here."
  - If you have two routes to the same network (the "Internet at large" counts as a network), and you want some traffic to go on one route and other traffic to go on another route, you are looking into configuring *policy based routing*.
  - Check [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html) out. I think it will at least get you started if this is what you are trying to accomplish. ([This too](https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/).)